# How to get exact decimal value from bigdecimal in java

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to get number of digits after decimal point in BigDecimal value.

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(1231235612.45);
    String[] str = big.toPlainString().split("\\.");

    System.out.println(" Decimal Value: " + str[1]);
```

Using this I am getting following output -
**Decimal Value: 4500000476837158203125**.
Actualy I want to display **only 45** as per the original BigDecimal value ***(1231235612.45)***.
So, my expected output is **Decimal Value: 45**.
But, while conversion it adds more digits after decimal points.
Is there any method or code to get exact same value from BigDecimal?

Comment: Long story short: use the `String` constructor instead.

Comment: Most likely you wanted `BigDecimal.valueOf(1231235612.45);` or `new BigDecimal("1231235612.45");`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the double Constructor of BigDecimal (See Javadoc, it is discouraged).

use String constructor

```
new BigDecimal("1231235612.45");
```

or use MathContext

```
new BigDecimal(1231235612.45, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
```

Comment: @Nilesh The reason to not use the double constructor is that 1231235612.45 gets put into a 64-bit double, which cannot exactly represent it in a finite number of bits, The number 1231235612.4500000476837158203125 is the closest it can get. Changing the value by one bit produces a number less than 1231235612.45, but not quite as close as the one shown.